# Making custom typeclasses: getting `can not deduce arising from <member function>` errors

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm just playing around with haskell and for the sake of an adventure, I'm not reading the Docs for haskell and trying to figure stuff out myself.

Here's my definition for the typeclass and type consturctor

```hs
data F a = T a 

class Mnd a b where
 xx :: (Num a)=>a->b->F a

instance Mnd Int (F Int) where
    x `xx` y = do
        let gf (a:_)  = a
        T $ gf [1..5] 

xxx::(Mnd ma mb)=>ma -> mb ->F ma
xxx  a b =    xx a 1
```

and I'm getting

```
haskellops.hs:41:12: error:
    • Could not deduce (Mnd ma Integer) arising from a use of ‘xx’
      from the context: Mnd ma mb
        bound by the type signature for:
                   xxx :: forall ma mb. Mnd ma mb => ma -> mb -> F ma
        at haskellops.hs:40:1-33
    • In the expression: xx a 1
      In an equation for ‘xxx’: xxx a b = xx a 1
   |
41 | xxx  a b = xx a 1
   |            ^^^^^
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

I declaired `(Mnd ma mb)=>ma -> mb ->F ma`, what's supposed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to call the function `xx`, you're passing two parameters to it - `ma` and `1`. First is of type `ma`, second is of type `Integer`.

So, looking at the signature of `xx`, the compiler sees that its two parameters are of types `a` and `b`, which come from the type class `Mnd a b` itself. So it matches `a` with `ma` and `b` with `Integer`, and proceeds to attempt to find an instance `Mnd ma Integer`.

How would it find such instance without knowing what `ma` is? Well, in cases where not all types are known, one would typically add a constraint to the function itself, and that's where the compiler will get the instance required. But look: your function has a constraint `Mnd ma mb`, which doesn't match `Mnd ma Integer` that the compiler is looking for.

So the compiler gives up. `Could not deduce (Mnd ma Integer) ... from the context: Mnd ma mb`

As to how to solve it - that really depends on what it is you're trying to do exactly. The dumbest way would be to just add a required constraint to `xxx`:

```
xxx :: (Mnd ma Integer) => ma -> mb -> F ma
xxx a b = xx a 1
```

This will compile, but I suspect (judging by that `instance Mnd Int (F Int)`) that you actually meant to do something *more* than just get `xxx` to compile.

But without knowing what it was, I can't give any further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `instance` is irrelevant here, as it doesn't influence type checking.  You would get the same error with the program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data F a = T a

class Mnd a b where
  xx :: (Num a) => a -> b -> F a

xxx :: (Mnd ma mb) => ma -> mb -> F ma
xxx a b = xx a 1
```

The problem is that the type of the numeric literal `1 :: Num n => n` is unrelated to any other types in the definition of `xxx`.  Therefore, the inferred type of the expression `xx a 1` is:

```
xx a 1 :: forall n. (Num n, Mnd ma n, Num ma) => F ma
```

where `n` is a type variable representing the unspecified type of `1`.

A type like this, where a forall-bound variable `n` appears in a constraint but not in the type itself, is ambiguous, and is generally disallowed by Haskell.  If it's not clear why these types are ambiguous, consider a program like the following:

```
class Typename b where
  typename :: b -> String
instance Typename Int where
  typename b = "Int"
instance Typename Integer where
  typename b = "Integer"

whatIsOne :: String
whatIsOne = typename 1

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn whatIsOne
```

However, there are some special rules that allow certain ambiguous types to be calculated by setting type variables to defaults.  In this case, the defaulting rules apply, and `n` is set to `Integer`.  This results in the inferred type:

```
xx a 1 :: (Mnd ma Integer, Num ma) => F ma
```

and since you're missing both `Mnd ma Integer` and `Num ma` constraints in your type signature, you get errors.  The program would type check if you wrote:

```
xxx :: (Mnd ma Integer, Num ma) => ma -> mb -> F ma
xxx a b = xx a 1
```

In this case, you probably didn't want the type of `1` to default to `Integer`.  To prevent this, you need to resolve the ambiguity, by assigning `1` a type.  My guess is that you most likely wanted `1` to have type `mb`.  You can use `asTypeOf` to accomplish this.  With the definition:

```
xxx a b = xx a (1 `asTypeOf` b)
```

which type checks even without an explicit type signature.  The inferred signature is:

```
xxx :: (Mnd ma mb, Num ma, Num mb) => ma -> mb -> F ma
```

which seems like what you probably wanted.